# How to display content in this case?

Tags: html, angular

Soooo, Im trying to do a messaging feature, and encountered a strange problem.
I can't display content from messages on browser, and i dont understand what I did wrong.
Can Someone explain to me why it doesn't work? And help to solve this problem?

Service:

```
GetMessageThread(email: string){
  return this.http.get<Message[]>(this.baseUrl+ 'Messages/thread/' + email);
}
```

Ts:

```
export class MemberMessagesComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() email!: string | any;
messages!: Message[];

constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadMessages();
}

loadMessages() {
  this.messageService.GetMessageThread(this.email).subscribe(email =>{
    this.email = email;
    console.log(this.email);
  })
}
```

HTML

```
<ul *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <li>{{ message?.content }}</li>
</ul>
```

The response works fine, it gets these messages, but nothing is displayed on the page

[The response from console.log(this.email)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Hlu.png)

I dont understand it... why doesnt it display 'content'?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this in your code:

```
loadMessages() {
  this.messageService.GetMessageThread(this.email).subscribe(response=>{
    this.messages = response;
    console.log(this.messages);
  })
}
```

By the way, you asked for the way:
As you sure as notice by now, you were asigning the response of your http call to the 'email' variable, and in your HTML code, you were trying to show the content of 'messages', not 'email'.

Comment: Yikes, avoid function call in templates, `messageService.GetMessageThread(email)` will be called everytime change detection happens

Comment: xD xD Fair enough! I will edit my answer and leave only the "good part" :) Thxs!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Message` into an Observable:

```
messages$!: Observable<Message[]>;
```

Then you can assign your Observable like so:

```
loadMessages() {
  this.messages$ = this.messageService.GetMessageThread(this.email);
}
```

On your template side:

```
<ul *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
    <li>{{ message?.content }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Work properly! Thank you so much :)